# Sumar 2 mínimos en un array (JS) Esta bien mi lógica?

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
const minSum=(arr)=>{
    let minimo1=Math.min(...arr)
    arr=arr.filter(n=> n!==minimo1)
    //elimino el primer minimo del array

    let minimo2=Math.min(...arr) //obtengo "el segundo minimo"
    let resultado=[minimo1+minimo2]
    return console.log(resultado)}

minSum([9,7,5,3,2,1])
```

Quiero saber si es la mejor forma de aplicar la suma de 2 minimos en un array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma mas sencilla es ordenar de menor a mayor y sumar los 2 primeros elementos

```js
const minSum=(arr)=>{
  arr.sort();    
  return arr[0] + arr[1];
}

console.log(minSum([9,7,5,3,2,1]))
```

Ya si quieres hacer mas comprobaciones podrías antes de hacer el llamado a minSum, comprobar que al menos tenga 2 elementos:

```js
const valores=[9];
const minSum=(arr)=>{
  arr.sort();    
  return arr[0] + arr[1];
}

if(valores.length<2){
  console.log("Deben existir al menos 2 valores");
} else {
  console.log(minSum(valores))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, veo algunas fallas en tu lógica. ¿Qué pasa si el array que te mandan viene vacío o tiene menos de dos elementos?

En aquellos casos, probablemente tus resultados serían incorrectos ya que podrían no existir `minimoUno` y/o `minimoDos`.

Aunque si bien, es una forma de resolverlo, la función filter va a recorrer todo el arreglo en busca del elemento menor. Y por lo tanto, con tu implementación actual, estás iterando `(N) + (N-1)` veces, donde `N` es el tamaño del arreglo.

Es decir, si tu arreglo es de 10 elementos, para obtener el primer mínimo habrás echo 10 iteraciones. En el segundo recorrido, para obtener el `minimo2` harás 9 iteraciones, ya que un elemento ha sido eliminado.

En total, habrías hecho 19 iteraciones solo para obtener dos números.

Una solución mucho más sencilla y que requiere `(N-2)` iteraciones es la siguiente:

```
const minSum = (arr) => {
    const tamanioArr = arr.length;

    if (arr.length === 0)
        return 0;

    if (arr.length === 1)
        return arr[0];

    if (arr.length === 2)
        return arr[0] + arr[1];

    let minUno = arr[0];
    let minDos = arr[1];

    // Si minDos es mayor a minUno, hay que cambiarlos para que minUno siempre sea el minimo menor
    if (minDos < minUno) {
        let aux = minUno;
        minUno = minDos;
        minDos = minUno;
    }

    for (let i = 2; i < tamanioArr; i++) {
        let aux = arr[i];

        if (aux < minUno && aux < minDos) {
            minDos = minUno;
            minUno = aux;
        } else if (aux < minDos) {
            minDos = aux;
        }
    }

    return minUno + minDos;
}

console.log(minSum([9,7,5,3,2,1])); // 3
console.log(minSum([7,7,7,7,7,7])); // 14
console.log(minSum([7,8])); // 15
console.log(minSum([])); // 0
console.log(minSum([234,45,2,35,1,34,345,123])); // 3
```